# Why does a Demon Hunter take more damage than a Monk with near-identical stats?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

I'm playing a DH teamed up with a Monk.

Based on our armour and hp stats - we should be very even when it comes to "tanking" or survivability.

My question is: **Why isn't it so?**

In a fight, he could stand there all day - doing nothing and I have to dodge like a maniac!
In huge fights, this is kinda impossible due to all the stuff/monsters flying about - and I always end up dead.

Does the DH take more damage due to it's class? 
Or are there any secret stats we should know about?

More info:

- The monk does not have much more dodge change
- I (the DH) actually have more armor than the monk
- The monk does not have any lifesteal

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Monks and Barbarians take 30% less damage than the other 3 classes. This is an inherent attribute valid from level 1.

Now, 30% is significant but I'm not sure it's enough to justify the radical difference you're describing. How certain are you that it's not just your general perception? Because in practice, a Monk does not tend to just stand there tanking. He tends to hit back, which often causes a "hit" animation on monsters which prevents them from attacking. This is before, of course, we consider that a typical Monk is loaded to the brim with skills that stun enemies, blind enemies, decrease enemy armor, increase the Monk's armor, etc.

Comment: It's not very intended on my end to get in their faces - but you know.. Hoards of enemies in small spacing is a tough spot for DHs.. Very good reply though, thanks alot!

Comment: @xstnc I think the monster's "getting hit interrupt" thing has a huge effect here. When *you* are cornered, you just want to get out of there and you don't even bother attacking everything, so the monsters have free reign. When the *Monk* is surrounded, he attacks everything with his AoE melee skills, interrupting them all.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like something that could make it feel like the diffrence is larger than what it really is. I'm glad I asked the question and got proper answers instead of just raging when I die! :D

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of reasons for that.

Monks and barbarians take 30% less damage by default.
Some other reasons include much higher armor due to the mote used skills/passives for most monks Some of them are:

- hard target rune for mantra of evasion boosts armor by 20%
- mantra of evasion pops a 2 min 15% boost to dodge, with an additional 15% for the 1st 3 sec
- Intimidate rune for mantra of conviction decreases all damage mobs do by 10%
- time of need rune for mantra of healing boosts all resistances by 20%
- One with everything passive sets all resistances to equal your highest resistance. Due to this passive and above stated time of need, monks usualy have very hihg resistance values (well over 1000, which brings them into the 80%+ dmg reduction range
- guardians path pops a 15% dodge chance if dual-wielding
- resolve passive reduces all damage from mobs you damage by 25% for 2.5 sec
- sieze the initiastive makes your dex also increase armor the same way strenght does
- cripling wave primary with concussion rune reduces all damage from mobs you hit by 20% for 3 sec
- fist of thunder with lightning flash rune increases your dodge by 16% for 2 sec
- Keen eye rune for the deadly reach primary which increases armor by 50% for 4 sec

The other reasons would probably be that most monks use a shield (increased armor, resistances, block% and blok amount) ant that most monks use some form of life stealing in some degree often combined with increases to att speed.

All these are some of the most common reason, there are of course others.

Answer (score 1):

Each class has various levels of squishiness. Demon Hunters just happen to be more squishy than one would expect.  This is because the primary attribute is dexterity, not vitality.  There are ways to counteract that squishiness, such as pluses to vitality, and during the mid game are much more beneficial than, say, increases to damage.  You still won't be able to tank that well, but if you're in a bad spot, it won't hurt as much.

Also, something to realize, the Demon Hunter is a ranged class.  They aren't meant to get up close and personal.  That's why you have [Vault](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/vault) and [Evasive Fire](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/evasive-fire), so that you don't stay in the thick of things.  Another important aspect of the Demon Hunter is crowd control: slowing down groups of enemies so that they are easier to handle.

Monks are much more adept at the up close kills.  They use melee weapons after all.  It's not much surprise then that your friend can absorb damage easier than you.

Comment: @xstnc: But that's where your crowd control abilities come in.  Lay a Caltrop and then get out of there with Vault, Evasive Fire, or Smoke Screen.

Comment: As of the post; I don't have much less vit(hp) than the monk. It's true that it's not the point to get in close, but sometimes you can't do anything about it! :( Well, it's surprising when the diffrence is that huge!

Comment: Yep! Caltrop and vaults are valuable!